# To change the level of a column from 0 to 1 in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'serial':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3],
       'lot':['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
       'part':['aa','ab','ac','ad','ae','af','ba','bb','bc','bd','be','bf','bg','ca','cb','cc'],
       'qty':[1,2,1,3,1,5, 2,3,4,5,3,2,1,2,3,3]})
```

[image]

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='serial', columns='lot')
```

[image]

I changed it using pivot, but this is not what I want

[image]

What I want is the data frame above

a, b, c go up, part and qty go down
(The level 0 and 1 of the column are switched)

How can I fix it? plz let me know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain `pivot` with `swaplevel` and `sort_index`:

```
df.pivot(index='serial', columns='lot').swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Or you can use `stack().unstack()` sequence like this:

```
df.set_index(['serial','lot']).stack().unstack(level=(1,2))
```

Output:

```
lot       a         b        c     
       part  qty part qty part  qty
serial                             
1        aa    1   ba   2   ca    2
2        ab    2   bb   3   cb    3
3        ac    1   bc   4   cc    3
4        ad    3   bd   5  NaN  NaN
5        ae    1   be   3  NaN  NaN
6        af    5   bf   2  NaN  NaN
7       NaN  NaN   bg   1  NaN  NaN
```